# should i use conditions in methods or make different methods?

Tags: php, laravel

Currently i have 2 options, in my controller i can either make different methods or i can make a single method and differentiate the working by using conditions. Let me elaborate.

i have researched about it but i couldn't get a reliable answer.

1) I can make two methods dealer() and subDealer() and do their workings separately.

2) I make a single dealers() method and in that i can check if that is a dealer or a sub dealer by using a single if statement, as majority of the work of these two will be same.

**which is better?**

Comment: That sort of logic should be in the service layer.

Comment: @tereško can you elaborate please?

Comment: Even though Laravel does not actually apply MVC pattern, it's still a good practice to adhere to `*Separation of Concerns*. In this case the "what type of dealer" is part of  the business logic. The handling of the "dealer" should be done in a separate service. Also, both those dealers probably would also have a shared interface. And no, I can't be less vague, because you question is very abstract with no concrete example or code.

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach is better - it would make Your code more elastic, reusable and cleaner. It's always better to make new function with very small responsibility which can be used multiple times than create one big monster which can be used only once.

Answer (score 0):

You should go with option one.
Its part of the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)principles (although its aimed at classes some of the ideas work for methods too). In this case the S stands for single responsibility. Each method should do one thing and one thing only.
Having a method do two or more tasks makes your code more tightly coupled and harder to maintain and debug later.

Comment: What you wrote has nothing to do with SRP.

Answer (score 0):

The first option is good to choose when we come to code reusability.